# HTTP CORS api query unknown error larave, forge, ionic

Tags: typescript, laravel, ionic-framework, cors

I have this error:

```
: 
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'abort', …}
headers
: 
fe {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message
: 
"Http failure response for https://www.dominio.com/api/login: 0 Unknown Error"
name
: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
: 
false
status
: 
0
statusText
: 
"Unknown Error"
url
: 
"https://www.dominio.com/api/login"
```

I was reading and I think it is CORS, the problem is that I don't know how to solve it, since I have FORGE as a server and I don't know how to modify the htaccess etc.

It is an IONIC application, the app when I run ionic serves to test, everything works 100% for me, in postman the requests work, the problem is that when I transform the app into an APK, I install it on Android and it gives me an error, I already have the internet permission since I thought that was it and no, I don't know what to do anymore.

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginI } from './../models/login.interface';
import { ResponseI } from './../models/response.interface';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  url:string = "https://www.dominio.com/api/"
  constructor( private http:HttpClient ) { }
    loginByEmail(form:LoginI):Observable<ResponseI>{
      let direccion = this.url + "login";
      return this.http.post<ResponseI>(direccion,form);
    }

}
```

**to bring my user data to the dashboard**
**dashboard.page.ts**

```
  checkLocalStorage(){
          const id = localStorage.getItem('id')
          const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

      if(id){
        console.log('Este es el id del cliente: ', id, token);
        this.userId = id;
      }
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
      const id = localStorage.getItem('id'); //guardar id
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

      this.http.get('https://www.dominio.com/api/user/show/' + id )
        .subscribe(
          (res) => {
            this.cliente = res;
            console.log(res)
          },
          (error) => {
            console.error('Error en la solicitud:', error);
            // errores
          }
        );
```

**In all the other components it is the same logic.**

**my Ngnix configuration cors**

```
location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
     
    
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

**login**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\api\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Cliente;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        
        $email = $request->input('usuario');
        $password = $request->input('password');
        
         
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password
        ];
        
         
        $user = Cliente::where('email', $email)->first();
        
         
        if (!$user || !Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Credenciales incorrectas'], 401);
        }
        
        $clienteData = [
            'id' => $user->id, // Por ejemplo, nombre es un atributo del cliente
            // Añade aquí todos los campos que desees devolver
        ];
        
         
        $token = $user->createToken('token-name')->plainTextToken;
    
         
        return response()->json(['status' => 'ok', 'result' => ['token' => $token, 'cliente' => $clienteData]]);
    }
}
```

**and finally the login.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {ApiService} from '../services/api.service';
import { LoginI } from '../models/login.interface'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ResponseI } from '../models/response.interface'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  alertButtons = ['Cerrar'];

  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    usuario : new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    password : new FormControl('',Validators.required)
  })
  constructor(private api:ApiService, private router:Router) { }

 errorStatus: boolean = false;
 errorMsj:any = ''; 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.checkLocalStorage();
  }

  checkLocalStorage(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    }
  }

  onLogin(form: any) {
    const loginData: LoginI = {
      usuario: form.usuario,
      password: form.password,
       
    };
    this.api.loginByEmail(loginData).subscribe(
      (data: ResponseI) => {
        if (data.status === 'ok') {
          localStorage.setItem('token', data.result.token);
          localStorage.setItem('id', data.result.cliente.id); // Almacena el ID del 

          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        // Manejar errores de red u otros errores del servidor
        console.error('Error en la solicitud:', error);
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.errorMsj = error.error.error;
          this.errorStatus = true;
        }
      }
    );
    
  }
  
}
```

I emphasize again, the requests in **postman** do work, when I run `Ionic serve` and the app is displayed on **localhost:8100** it also works perfectly,

The commands I use to create the apk are

1. `ionic build`
2. `npx cap add android`
3. `npx cap open android`

When the apk is created and I inspect it from chrome://inspect/#devices it appears that the APP running on android runs at **https:localhost/login**